# cs0131 The left-hand side of an assingnment must be a variable, property or indexer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

Getting error on: CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer. Error starts at: string checkuser = "select count(*) from Uregistration where Firstname='"

I have tried multiple different solutions provided by online channels but still cannot fix this error.

```cs
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegiConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
string checkuser = "select count(*) from Uregistration where Firstname='" = TextBox1.Text + "'";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

if (temp == 1)
{
    Response.Write("User Already Exists");
}
conn.Close();
```

How can I get this sentence valid? string checkuser = "select count(*) from Uregistration where Firstname='"

Comment: string checkuser = "select count(*) from Uregistration where Firstname='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";

Comment: The `= TextBox1.Text` should be `+ TextBox1.Text`. However, you should *definitely* be using parameterized SQL instead of string concatenation like this. Currently - well, after you've fixed it to compile - you'd have a SQL Injection Attack vulnerability.

Comment: As the error says, you can assign something only to a variable, property, or indexer. In your case, you're trying to assign the value of `TextBox1.Text` to a string. I think wht you want is cncatenate the two strings, so use `+` instead.

Comment: Thanks so much Sach! Please if you can assist with the last one? {
                Response.Write("error" = ex.ToString());
            }

Comment: @AllendeKoker, query concatenation is always a bad idea, it leads to security issues such as SQL injection. plz check you this link https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Mandatory [XKCD](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png).

Comment: @AllendeKoker Obviously, that has the same incorrect `=` instead of `+`.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments noted, you've placed an `=` where you need to place a `+` when concatenating `TextBox1.Text` to the string literal.

However, you should not be using string concatenation to build your SQL statements, especially when taking values entered directly by the user. Doing so will open you up to a SQL Injection Attack.

Instead, you should use a parameterized query.

```csharp
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegiConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
string checkuser = "select count(*) from Uregistration where Firstname=@Firstname";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Firstname", TextBox1.Text);
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

if (temp == 1)
{
    Response.Write("User Already Exists");
}
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks so much! What a great community !!